# Unable to interact with the text field of website using selenium webdriver (using dynamic xpath)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to fill the input text field named Destination on a website and I am getting the error that "element not interactable". I searched and found that there could be temporary or permanent overlay so I tried using wait(implicit and explicit) but it didn't help.

**On Mozila I am getting the error: **

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element  is not reachable by keyboard

**And on chrome : ** org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Here's the code:

```
    public void check() throws InterruptedException {
         System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver();
          driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/home"); //navigate to the particular url
          driver.manage().window().maximize();  // maximizes of the window 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
              driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'][@class='select2-input'])[5]")).sendKeys("abc"); //search field


    }
```

And yes I have imported all the prerequisites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your issue you can use selenium wait and action chain. ElementNotInteractableException is occurs due to overlay elements , element is not visible or clickable.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.phptravels.net/home")
selectElement=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='s2id_autogen1']//input[@id='s2id_autogen2']")))
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(selectElement).click().perform()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='s2id_autogen1']//input[@id='s2id_autogen2']"))).send_keys("Enter your Text")
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

[image]